# Jhipster failure build war file

Tags: build, war, jhipster, yarnpkg

I use this `mvn -Pprod` and I get errors like this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) on project jhi: Failed to run task: 'yarn run webpack:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteE
xception: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Arguments: 
  E:\vaqtinchalik\Vaqf\jhiProject\node\node.exe E:\vaqtinchalik\Vaqf\jhiProject\node\yarn\dist\bin\yarn.js install --force

PATH: 
  E:\vaqtinchalik\Vaqf\jhiProject\node;E:\vaqtinchalik\Vaqf\jhiProject\node\yarn\dist\bin;E:\vaqtinchalik\Vaqf\jhiProject\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;E:\maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\JavaProgUZ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\JavaProgUZ\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\JavaProgUZ\AppData\Roaming\npm;

Yarn version: 
  1.3.2

Node version: 
  8.9.4

Trace: 
  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\vaqtinchalik\Vaqf\jhiProject\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-57\binding.node'

Comment: You're not showing the real error from webpack, please edit your question with full trace

Comment: you mean file webpack.prod.js

Comment: No, I mean the full trace of your maven build where we can see the webpack error, you can use gist to share it